# Django Rest Framework, how to add Serializer field from list of names

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework Serializer that contains many float fields, e.g.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    unitID = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=50)
    timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True)
    VonDC = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
    VonAC = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
    VoffDC = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
    VonDC2 = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
    etc...
```

I would like to be able to create these fields from a list of field names, e.g.

```
the_fields = ['VonDC', 'VonAC', 'VoffDC', 'VonDC2', etc...] 

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    unitID = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=50)
    timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True)

    for f in the_fields:
        <something>[f] = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
        or
        <some_function>(<something>, f, serializers.FloatField(required=False) )
```

I haven't been able to find what "something" or "some_function" in the above would be.

Is it possible to do this? 
Is there a way in python to add attributes to a class and take the name from a variable?
Or is there specific support for this in Django Rest Framework?

I want to do it partly because it's more concise but mainly because I already have a list of the field names that I want to provide and I want to use it rather than repeat all the names.

(The list of fields is essentially fixed, there are system wide implications to changing it. It might get changed occasionally, but it certainly won't change while the program is running)

Answer (score 1):

try to override the **`__init__()`** method of serializer as below,

```
the_fields = ['VonDC', 'VonAC', 'VoffDC', 'VonDC2', ]


class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    unitID = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=50)
    timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in the_fields:
            self.fields.update({field: serializers.FloatField(required=False)})
```

Comment: This adds the field directly to an instance rather than listing it in the class. I can see that this might just be explictly doing what normally happens behind the scenes. I would worry that it might not be doing *everything* that normally happens behind the scenes. Something might rely on the field being listed on the class and so not work as expected.

Comment: It's not possible to list the fields in class as ***class variables*** with the help of for loop

Answer (score 1):

I think that 'normally' the following code would do the job of adding the FloatFields as attributes of the class.

Note that the for loop is after the class, not in its body.

```
the_fields = ['VonDC', 'VonAC', 'VoffDC', 'VonDC2', etc...] 

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    unitID = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=50)
    timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True)

for name in meas_names:
    setattr(MySerializer, name, serializers.FloatField(required=False))
```

However serializers.Serializer has a metaclass that includes special handling of any "Field" attributes that are present in the class body. The FloatFields that are added by the for loop are added after the metaclass has done its work so are not handled correctly.

The metaclass removes any "Field" attributes that it finds and moves them into a _declared_fields dict instead.

So it looks as if we can add Fields to the class by adding them directly to _declared fields.

```
the_fields = ['VonDC', 'VonAC', 'VoffDC', 'VonDC2', etc...] 

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    unitID = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=50)
    timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(required=True)

for name in meas_names:
    MySerializer._declared_fields[name] = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
```